# "Local RT kernel: The connection is broken."--> Getting this error while calling a function in my capl code (the function is in dll file)

Tags: dll, capl, canoe

I Have added my dll file into capl code. when trying to use the function in my capl script iam getting this error "Local RT kernel: The connection is broken."

I would like to know if anyone has encountered the same and how to tackle this problem . Thankyou

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You get this error message, when the runtime-kernel process is terminated,. most likely due to a crash. You should provide much more information on what you are doing.